# Custom Segue from a dynamic table view using storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view controller with a ViewController in a storyboard, the view contains a button and a table view.

I add a custom segue when pressing the button, it works fine. When I add the same custom segue to the same new view controller for the prototype cells, nothing happens. The perform on the segue is never called.

Do I have to do it in code, or should this work using interface builder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work, as long as the prototype cells are the cells you're really using in your table (e.g you just dequeue them using the identifier in the storyboard, there is no separate initialisation of the cell).

If all else fails, you can define the segue directly from one view controller to the next and call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` in your did select row delegate method.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot to set the identifier in IB